# Windows Forms App not being ran in full size

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a size-sensitive windows forms application right now and I noticed because I'm creating a bitmap that's the size of the form, that the form is slightly shorter than it's `Size.Height` property when it's created, is there any way to fix this and preferably lock the form so the user can't resize it.

Comment: ClientRectangle and Bounds are different. If you're interested in content size you should check ClientSize (it'll update Bounds). To make it fixed just change border to fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, that the form's size (`Form.Size`) differs from its client area size (`Form.ClientSize`). The difference equals to the width of window's border.
To prevent a user from resizing your form, set the appropriate value to the form's `FormBorderStyle` property.

Answer (score 1):

You may be mistaken about the size of the form. The form is exactly as specified in Size.Height. However, there are things like title and borders that makes the usable area smaller.

You can check the usable area by looking into the [ClientSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/9278sfx2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

If you want to keep your form not resizable, you can use the [FormBorderStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.form.formborderstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.